# Calculate date difference in (hours,mins) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am looking at calculating the date difference between two columns and display the output in a 3rd column in hours, minutes.

```
       Submitted                     Approved            TimeTaken
  2016-04-15 10:00:00           2016-04-15 10:13:00         0.13
  2016-04-15 10:00:00           2016-04-15 11:38:00         1.38
```

I already have all the tables and data for the dates. I was just wondering if the example above is a possible output.

As an extension to this, is it possible to only count the hours for `TimeTaken` between 8am-6pm?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249778/datediff-to-output-hours-and-minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the difference as hours and minutes.  Just use decimal hours:

```
select datediff(second, submitted, approved) / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
```

The extension is much trickier:

```
select (case when cast(submitted as date) = cast(approved as date)
             then datediff(second, submitted, approved)
             else (datediff(day, submitted, approved) - 1) * 10*60*60 +
                  datediff(second, cast(submitted as time), '20:00') +
                  datediff(second, '08:00', cast(approved as time))
        end) / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
```

If you have more extensions -- such as avoiding weekends and holidays -- then ask another question.  Don't edit this one.

Answer (score 0):

For short periods and low precision you can use datediff but keep in mind that it doesn't return the elapsed time but boundaries crossed.
Theese examples give you an idea of what I mean:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YY, '31/12/2016',  '01/01/2017') FakeYears

FakeYears
1

SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '01/01/2017 00:59:59',  '01/01/2017 01:00:00') FakeHours

FakeHours
1
```

see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446566/creating-a-duration-function-in-sql-server/41570517#41570517) for extended explanation and solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try below :

```
SELECT Submitted,
   Approved,
   REPLACE(LEFT(CAST(Approved - Submitted AS TIME(2)), 5), ':', '.') TimeTaken;
```

**Result:**

```
Submitted                Approved                 TimeTaken
2016-04-15 10:00:00.000  2016-04-15 10:13:00.000    00.13
2016-04-15 10:00:00.000  2016-04-15 11:38:00.000    01.38
```

Now, you can convert it as you need in above.